# Yii CCheckBoxColumn not working properly

Tags: php, yii

I created a table with checkbox but its not working the increment number not oming properly and emails and allowed connection are not properly aligned   please see my code and image[image]

```
'columns'=>array(
        array(
             'class' => 'CCheckBoxColumn',
             'selectableRows' => 2,
             'checkBoxHtmlOptions' => array(
             'name' => 'ids[]',),
             'value' => '$data->id',
             'cssClassExpression'=>'$data->status == 0 ? "" : "hidden"',


        ),
        array(
            'header'=>'No.',
            'value'=>'$this->grid->dataProvider->pagination->currentPage*$this->grid->dataProvider->pagination->pageSize + $row+1',       //  row is zero based
        ),
        array('header' => 'Name', 'value' => '$data->Users->name'),
        array('header' => 'Email', 'value' => '$data->Users->email'),
        array('header' => 'Date Requested', 'value' => 'date("M j, Y", strtotime($data->date_requested))'),
        array('header' => 'Requested Connections','value' => '$data->connections_requested'),
        array('header' => 'Allowed Connections','type' => 'raw','value' => '($data->status == 0) ? "<input class=\"copr-connections\" type=\"text\" name=\"connections_".$data->id."\" value=\"".$data->connections_requested ."\">" : $data->connections_accepted'),
        array('header' => 'Request Status','value' => '($data->status == 0) ? "Pending" : (($data->status == 1) ? "Accepted" : "Rejected")'),

    ),
));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You hide with `'cssClassExpression'=>'$data->status == 0 ? "" : "hidden"',` whole table cell.

When you generate table each row `<tr>` must consider equal number of `<td>` tags or you must use `rowspan` or `colspan` attributes. Your table structure looks like

```
<tr>
    <td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <!-- first td skiped, as it was hidden and table looks broken --><td>2</td><td>3</td>
</tr>
```

It will be better just disable checkbox you won't be checked. Here is a possible solution to do this: http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/20495-disable-checkbox-in-ccheckboxcolumn-based-on-attribute-value/

```
// Extended CCheckBoxColumn class
class myCheckBoxColumn extends CCheckBoxColumn
{
    public $disabled;
    protected function renderDataCellContent($row,$data)
    {
        if($this->disabled!==null)
            $this->checkBoxHtmlOptions['disabled']=$this->evaluateExpression($this->disabled,array('data'=>$data,'row'=>$row));
        parent::renderDataCellContent($row,$data);
    }
}

// View example
'columns'=>array(
   'id',
   'name',
   array(
    'class'=>'myCheckBoxColumn',
    'name'=>'checkfield',
    'disabled'=>'$data->checkfield',
   ),
)
```